# Will firebase-admin-node start to return date's as Timestamp from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In my team we are using firebase/firestore in an Angular application, powered by firebase functions. It works great!

Currently we are converting our code in the Angular application, because firestore now returns date's as Timestamp (and not js-dates).

Is this something that firebase-admin-node will do as well - or will it stick to js-dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we don't have a timeline for you, we are planning to expose Timestamps via the Firebase Admin SDK as well.

I will update this post as we get closer to a new release.

Update: v0.15.2 contains the Timestamp class.

Comment: Do you know if it's going to be optional, or maybe a setting where you can define if you wan't js-dates or Timestamp?

Comment: We are planning to gradually migrate all clients to use Timestamps that expose higher precision (to match the behavior on the backend). The new setting will be optional at first, but eventually our goal is to only support the new types.

Comment: We just released Firestore Node v0.15.2 that includes a Timestamp API similar to the Web client.