# How do I tell Firestore to return Timestamp objects using the Node Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, google-api-nodejs-client

Does the Node Firebase Admin SDK support returning Timestamp objects?

The NodeJs Firebase client library recommends setting the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting when initializing Firestore, but I can't seem to find an equivalent way to do this with the admin sdk.

Comment: check my q and a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364214/will-firebase-admin-node-start-to-return-dates-as-timestamp-from-firestore

Comment: Perfect, thanks @DauleDK